# Properly Granting Users Access to Google Cloud Platform Service Accounts Using the Cloud SDK CLI

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-iam, google-cloud-iam, google-cloud-sdk

Given a Google Cloud Platform (GCP) service account `$GCP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME`, what is the proper way to grant users the:

- permissions to deploy jobs and virtual machines with `$GCP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME`
- permission to administer `$GCP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME`

using the GCP Cloud SDK (`gcloud`) instead of [this](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts/create) page in the console?

In other words, if `$GCP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME` was created within GCP project `$GCP_PROJECT_NAME`:

```sh
gcloud iam service-accounts create $GCP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME \
--description=$GCP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_DESCRIPTION \
--display-name=$GCP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME

#=>

Created service account [$GCP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME].
```

and was granted permissions through some curated role:

```sh
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding $GCP_PROJECT_NAME \
--member="serviceAccount:$GCP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME@$GCP_PROJECT_NAME.iam.gserviceaccount.com" \
--role=$GCP_CURATED_ROLE

#=>

Updated IAM policy for project [$GCP_PROJECT_NAME].
bindings:
. . .
- members:
  . . .
  - serviceAccount:$GCP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME@$GCP_PROJECT_NAME.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: $GCP_CURATED_ROLE
  . . .
. . .
etag: . . .
version: 1
```

what `gcloud` group(s) and command would grant users the permissions to deploy jobs & virtual machines with and the permission to administer `$GCP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME`?

The official GCP documentation for creating a service account using `gcloud`, found [here](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#creating), suggests an `add-iam-policy-binding` command that would "allow users to impersonate the service account":

```sh
gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding \
$GCP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME@$GCP_PROJECT_NAME.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
--member="user:$GCP_USER_NAME" \
--role="roles/iam.serviceAccountUser"

#=>

Updated IAM policy for serviceAccount [$GCP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME@$GCP_PROJECT_NAME.iam.gserviceaccount.com].
bindings:
- members:
  - user:$GCP_USER_NAME
  role: roles/iam.serviceAccountUser
etag: . . .
version: 1
```

with:

```sh
gcloud config list account --format="value(core.account)"

#=>

$GCP_USER_NAME
```

Does this mean that `$GCP_USER_NAME` is able to deploy jobs and virtual machines with `$GCP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME`, administer `$GCP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME` or both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Binding the `roles/iam.serviceAccountUser` curated role grants `$GCP_USER_NAME_ALPHA` the permissions to deploy jobs and virtual machines with `$GCP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME`:

```sh
gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding \
$GCP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME@$GCP_PROJECT_NAME.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
--member="user:$GCP_USER_NAME_ALPHA" \
--role="roles/iam.serviceAccountUser"

#=>

Updated IAM policy for serviceAccount [$GCP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME@$GCP_PROJECT_NAME.iam.gserviceaccount.com].
bindings:
- members:
  - user:$GCP_USER_NAME_ALPHA
  role: roles/iam.serviceAccountUser
etag: . . .
version: 1
```

Binding the `roles/iam.serviceAccountAdmin` curated role grants `$GCP_USER_NAME_BETA` the permission to administer `$GCP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME`:

```sh
gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding \
$GCP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME@$GCP_PROJECT_NAME.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
--member="user:$GCP_USER_NAME_BETA" \
--role="roles/iam.serviceAccountAdmin"

#=>

Updated IAM policy for serviceAccount [$GCP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME@$GCP_PROJECT_NAME.iam.gserviceaccount.com].
bindings:
- members:
  - user:$GCP_USER_NAME_BETA
  role: roles/iam.serviceAccountAdmin
etag: . . .
version: 1
```

If `$GCP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME` was created using the console ([here](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts/create)) instead of `gcloud`, bindings can still be verified with:

```sh
gcloud iam service-accounts get-iam-policy \
$GCP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME@$GCP_PROJECT_NAME.iam.gserviceaccount.com

#=>

bindings:
- members:
  - user:$GCP_USER_NAME_BETA
  role: roles/iam.serviceAccountAdmin
- members:
  - user:$GCP_USER_NAME_ALPHA
  role: roles/iam.serviceAccountUser
etag: . . .
version: 1
```

The official GCP docs. *do* mention both roles [here](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#permissions), but **don**'**t** use the same language found in the Service Account creation portion of the console.  There also is **not** an "Equivalent COMMAND LINE" dialog on [this](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts/create) page.